# Typescript library organisation

Tags: typescript, import, organization

I just converted a javascript library to typescript.
My problem is that I don't know how to organize it.
It's a library including components, each, using different classes, types, error classes, etc... Some components depend of others components.

My initial approach was to export everything at the root level.

```
export * from "./component1";
export * from "./component2";
export * from "./component3";
```

So I can use it like this:

```
import { MyClassFromComponent1, MyTypeFromComponent2 } from "mylib"
```

It's ok to use, but it's all in the same place and with IDE and autocompletion, it's kind of messy.

My second approach was to import all components and export each one of them as a constant in the root index.ts

```
import * as _component1 from "./component1";
import * as _component2 from "./component2";
import * as _component3 from "./component3";

export const component1 = _component1;
export const component2 = _component2;
export const component3 = _component3;
```

And I was able to use it like this:

```
import component1 from "mylib"

const { MyClass1 } = component1;
```

But this way, I'm unable to import typescript types and I'm not able to do import destructuring like (as of course it's not supported with named imports)

```
import { component1: { MyClassComponent1 } } from "mylib"
```

Is there a recommended way to handle case like that? What about namespaces (I have to say that it's still confusing to me).

Comment: I do like the pattern with index.ts which exports all the components/functions for the library and then use `import { MyClassFromComponent1, MyTypeFromComponent2 } from "mylib"`. Why is that messy, didn't quite grasp your problem with that approach, for me the second approach seems more complex.

Comment: Actually, the only thing that I don't like in this approach is with autocompletion. Classes are orderer by name, so the classes don't appear grouped by "component".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today's best approach is to:

- export simple functions, classes, constants as they are, not wrapping them in some object or class. So your first approach `import { MyClassFromComponent1, MyTypeFromComponent2 } from "mylib"` is very good (i'll discuss namespacing later). This way your package will be tree-shakeable, which simply means a bundler like Webpack/Parcer can only extract from your package what exactly is required by the user.
- avoid default export. Frankly I forgot why, but this is a convention nowadays.

About namespacing. The common way is just having main functions, classes and other exportables in `main` script (which is defined by package.json's `main` field). Any other stuff is usually placed in its own subfolder (this subfolder is located in the same place with `main` script). 
So importing stuff from your package would look like this:

```
import {importantFunc, importantComponent} from "mylib"
import {secondaryStuff} from "mylib/feature1"
```

My personal approach, though, if you are interested, is to place the `main` script and all the subfolders in "./api" folder, so imports would look like this:

```
import {importantFunc, importantComponent} from "mylib/api"
import {secondaryStuff} from "mylib/api/feature1"
```

I like this way because it gives user a clear view of what exactly is exposed by the package. Otherwise, the user may not be confident if `"mylib/feature1"` is importable (i.e. is part of API) or it is just internal stuff of the package.

Comment: Hum... I really like the sub folders approach as it would allow me to get  autocompletion only for a specific component. But how do you manage with the usual src/ and dist/ folder? I don't want to have to import from an ugly "mylib/dist/component1" (or even an api subfolder). I can't output the compilation at the root of the package (or I wouldn't be able to clean it properly like rm -rf dist/).

Comment: I am personally dislike having my code in `src/` and `dist/`. I like having my `.js` files right next to the `.ts` files. However the common approach is the opposite. Each approach has its own pros and cons, but I choose what I choose. I didn't want to import from the `mylib/api` subfolder, but it seemed for me as a less ugly/more elegant solution than seeing all the stuff like package.json etc. in IDE autocompletion options.

Comment: "I can't output the compilation at the root of the package" - I never said to do it. You place your main script to the <project_root>/api folder and feature stuff to the <project_root>/api/featureX

Comment: I feel like I didn't completely answered your last questions, because I didn't understood them completely. I'll be glad to answer on this subject more, if you elaborate, because it bugged me exactly the same way as it did you.

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no perfect solution. Another approach would be the one use for example on material-ui. One repository, with the source, and the compiled npm package contains only the compiled code at the root of the package.

Comment: The whole programming thing is a tradeoff. So yes, you should have a look at different approaches, choose what suits you, and move on.